# Изменить цвет элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть такой вот элемент, цвета подтягиваются с АПИ, конкретного типа персонажа, нужно сделать так, чтобы он был полупрозрачным.

```
                        <div
                          className="progressBarFill"
                          style={{
                            background: typeColors[data.types[0].type.name],
                            width: stat.base_stat,
                          }}
                        ></div>
```

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Вы не указали, что такое typeColors[data... ] какие значения там хранятся... По такому вопросу очень сложно предложить хоть какое либо решение

Comment: @SwaD в typeColors указанны параметры для конкретного типа персонажа. 
пример:  
const typeColors = {
    bug: '#A7B723',
    dragon: '#7037FF',
    fairy: '#E69EAC',

Comment: В style добавьте `opacity: 0.5` тогда, должно сработать

Comment: @SwaD скорее всего не 0.5, а 50%

Comment: @Arcadiy 0.5, и 50% - одно и то же